# What are the steps of pose estimation for 3D object, in case of 6 Dof?

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, pose-estimation, ransac

I have 3D object (soft surface like aircraft wing) and want to use the deep learning tools to register the object using ICP, perform 6 Dof translation and rotation on the object. I have studied many libraries, methods of pose estimation, filtering, normalization, and image rendering but still not clear what are the steps or general pipeline? like someone using Intrinsic shape signatures ISS for capture the points of the object, or (SHOT) feature description and Random Sample Consensus (RANSAC) feature matching method to coarse registration.

My tools are: IMU, depth camera (D435), laser for tracking and HoloLens 2.

I need help to understand what the general required steps are, based on what I decide to select algorithm.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have reproduced the problem, not reached to the code level yet.